# Calculating player ratings

Tags: algorithm, coldfusion, cfml

Below I have two players that win or lose and their score fluctuates using the Elo function. I have adapted this code from something closer to my language which is ActionScript. I found [the functions here](http://jobemakar.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/why-the-elo-rating-system-rocks/). It is an older example and I didn't really get the point of it. My code is in ColdFusion. The problem I have with the code was that it spins through a 'single player' and the player's score started to go down. In addition, the poster only accounted for one Player.  Mine has two players.

In coldfusion there is log10() but if I reverse things and plant a player2 victory it gives a divide by zero error so I am doing 10^. This may be wrong.

To expand, how do I avoid a divide by zero on a result of -.42 using log10() while it works using 10^ ? Now, I have compensated using the if statement following the elo equation on the 'outcome' flag for playerone to get the 'result' to look like a score, but I could be generating the result wrong.

This is my best interpretation of the Elo function in ColdFusion. If something is wrong or can be improved, let me know what it is and how I should fix it.

```
function determineRatingConstant(required numeric rating) {

    // Some rating contants depending strong or weak ratings.
    // Note I want the middle range wins to count higher
    // because players in that spectum would face higher competition
    // You might see this differntly or this could be 
    var returnVal = 10;
    if (rating GT 2400) {       
        returnVal = 50;     
    } else if (rating GT 2300 AND rating LTE 2400) {
        returnVal = 40;
    } else if (rating GT 2200 AND rating LTE 2300) {
        returnVal = 30;
    } else if (rating GT 2100 AND rating LTE 2200) {
        returnVal = 20; 
    } else if (rating GT 2000 AND rating LTE 2100) {
        returnVal = 10;                                     
    } else {
        returnVal = 5;
    }
    return returnVal;
}

function calculateNewRating(required numeric player1Rating, required numeric player2Rating, required numeric player1Victory){
    var outcome = 0;
    if (player1Victory) {
        outcome = 1;
    }

    // in coldfusion there is log10() but if I reverse things and plant a 
    // player2 victory it gives a divide by zero error so I am doing 10^
    // is this right?
    var expected_outcome = 1/(1+10^((player1Rating-player2Rating)/400));
    var k = determineRatingConstant(player1Rating);
    var newrating = round(player1Rating+k*(outcome-expected_outcome));

    // I am not sure I am doing this right but
    // there are sometimes decimals and negatives 
    // I need to deal with... this could be unnecessary
    // because I could be doing it wrong in expected 
    // outcome when I reverse things.
    if (outcome eq 0){
        newrating = round(abs(newrating));  
    }   

    return newrating;
}

// Here we call our functional stuff...
// Ok I am creating a struct here and I am setting some starting variables
// as you can see I have player two at an advantage.
// I give player A the first win too.
player = structNew();
player.rating1 = 2150;
player.rating2 = 2200;

// Lets run through 25 games and see the fate of your two players.
// Also if marktWin eq 1 that is a win for Player1
for (i=0;i<25;++i) {
    if ( i eq 0 ) {
       marktWin = 1;
    } else {
       marktWin = randrange(0,1); //you can comment this out to see player one have an unfair advantage
    }

    player.rating1 = calculateNewRating(player.rating1, player.rating2, (marktWin ? 1 : 0));
    player.rating2 = calculateNewRating(player.rating2, player.rating1, (marktWin ? 0 : 1));
    writeOutput("game " & numberformat(i,'00')); //doing this to get a clean output 
    writeOutput(" : " & player.rating1 & " | " & player.rating2); // NOTE: inital player. struct values are overwritten
    writeOutput(" - Player 1:"); // below ternary operator funzies in Coldfusion
    writeOutput((marktWin ? " <span style='color:blue'><b>won</b></span>" : " <span style='color:red'>lost</span>")); 
    writeOutput("<br>"); 
}
```

Here is output of 25 games under normal conditions.

[image: Normal Elo Output]

And here is what happens when I let player one win every time.

[image]